# Ошибка конфигурации проекта java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present

Tags: java, spring

У меня возникла ошибка, при запуске Томкат 10 и java 19. Я создал проект и пока лишь создал конфигурацию для него. подключив Hibernate и Spring, ну и некоторые доп зависимости. работаю на бесплатной версии Pycharm, томкат запустил правильно. проблема в самом конфиге

Вот мой pom.xml

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.musa.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>Employee_Spring_Project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Employee_Spring_Project Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency><!--добавляем спринг MVC он так же добавит spring core, beans, context, aop итд-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency><!--апишка для томкат 10 исп jakarta-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency><!--реализация правил java standart bean validator api от hibernate -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.1</version>
    </dependency><!--подгружаем драйвер для JDBC PostgreSQL-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency><!--jstl для томкат 10.0.x-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Employee_Spring_Project</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

Вот мой web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
        version="5.0">

  <display-name>Employee_Spring_Project</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Вот мой applicationContext.xml, мой конфигурационный файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.musa.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop" />
    <!--указываем где будет проходить сканирование-->

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean><!--создаем префикс и суффикс-->


    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employee_spring_project?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="haniev2005" />
    </bean><!--подключим бд с помщью c3p0. это общий пул для подключения к бд. в отличии от стандартных
     подключений JDBC, которые очень затратные. это подключение. хранится ещё некоторое время. и если вновь
     обратиться к бд, то новое создавать не нужно. и это более производительней-->


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /><!--ссылается на наш пул подключений к бд-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.musa.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop.entity" /><!--указываем пакет для сканирования наших Entity классов-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop><!--чтобы мы видели в терминале какие запросы выполняются-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean><!--создание сессий-->

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/><!--указываем ссылку на бин производства сессий-->
    </bean><!--с помощью этого конфига мы можем больше не открывать и закрывать транзакции, можно по желанию конечно
    но даже без этого, Hibernate теперь сделает это за нас-->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /><!--а для активации автоматических
     транзакций пропишем это-->


</beans>
```

в ответ я получаю ошибку

```
    java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1250)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:500)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:448)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getFactoryBeanGeneric(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:910)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:572)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:720)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1011)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4907)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5214)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:693)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1979)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:586)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1449)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        ... 67 more
```

на Томкат 9 все запускается, но мне нужен именно 10 томкат. хотелось бы понять что я сделал не так

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 10 не поддерживает javax, замените все javax на jakarta

Comment: Я знаю об этом, приглядись к коду, у меня нет javax, я использую лишь jakarta